# how to sign apk in my application?(similar ApkEditor.apk)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a similar software Apk Editor.apk that will sign after editing apk
  Question:
What is the method of doing the sign apk in application?

Answer (score 0):

Everything about signing your app you can find in Android documentation.

Look here -> https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: how to sigin apk after edit on java? I not find Information about it

Comment: So again. First you have to decompile app, then you can edit it. After all, recompile and then sign android app. 
I recommend you use iJ IDE or just Apktool.